# Find out all files which are 'source' the given tcl file

Tags: grep, tcl

Is it possible to find out all files which are sources the given .tcl files?

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you're asking but these other questions may help: [How to find the location of TCL procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651549/how-to-find-the-location-of-tcl-procedure) and [Getting path of the proc in TCL which is invoked from another script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193268/getting-path-of-the-proc-in-tcl-which-is-invoked-from-another-script).

Comment: Do you want to know what sources the file, or what the file sources?

Answer (score 3):

Your best options are to either replace [`source`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/source.htm) or add a [`trace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm) for [`source`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/source.htm)

example with trace:

```
proc putargs args {puts $args}
trace add execution enter source {putargs SOURCE}
source /path/to/your/file.tcl
```